# Import always show changes

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

I have problem with import/export. After import it always says that there is changes after sync.
[image: details]

Anyone faced this issues? How to fix it (showing no changes after import all)?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself problem. Export full create different .yml file than export single. That why it make some fields lost.
Besides, the export function might ignore hidden fields in .yml files. In this case it should add fields manually to avoid conflict.
[image]